# header variables go missing in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm running Rails 3.1 with PhusionPassenger and NGINX in the back.  I'm sending requests via a simple HttpClient (GrahpicalHttpClient for OS X).  My code expects a token and an ID in the header to verify the authenticity of the caller.  In developement mode this is no problem, but once I move it into production the header variables go missing.  Nothing is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
@caller = Person.check_authentication_token(request.headers['person_id'], request.headers['authentication_token'])
```

The method check_authentication_token returns nil if either variable is nil.  As I said, this works fine in development but the request.headers['person_id'] and request.headers['authentication_token'] are both nil in production.  Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nginx defaults to considering underscores in request headers invalid and subsequently removes them, see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#underscores_in_headers for how to fix this.

Comment: Also happens with Apache. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-underscores-are-forbidden-in-http-header-names

Comment: Saved my life. I was going crazy due to SOME headers showing up and some not (the ones with underscores)