# Running jasperserver behind nginx: Potential CSRF attack

Tags: nginx, proxy, csrf, jasperserver, owasp

We are using nginx for https traffic offloading, proxying to a locally installed jasperserver (5.2) running on port 8080.

```
internet ---(https/443)---> nginx ---(http/8080)---> tomcat/jasperserver
```

When accessing the jasperserver directly on its port everything is fine. When accessing the service through nginx some functionalities are broken (e.g. editing a user in the jasperserver UI) and the jasperserver log has entries like this:

```
CSRFGuard: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:%user%, ip:%remote_ip%, uri:%request_uri%, error:%exception_message%)
```

After some debugging we found the cause for this:

In its standard configuration nginx is not forwarding request headers that contain underscores in their name. Jasperserver (and the OWASP framework) however default to using underscores for transmitting the csrf token (`JASPER_CSRF_TOKEN` and `OWASP_CSRFTOKEN` respectively).

Solution is to either:

- nginx: allow underscores in headers

  ```
  server {
     ...
     underscores_in_headers on;
  ```
- jasperserver: change token configuration name in `jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/esapi/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties`

Also see here:

- [header variables go missing in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295808/header-variables-go-missing-in-production)
- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#underscores_in_headers

Comment: Same issue, but the resolutions here didn't work for me - I posted a new question so hopefully additional info will show up there:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691799/jasperserver-proxy-csrf-error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered it myself - hopefully this is of some use to others,too

Comment: Setting `underscores_in_headers on;` solve the problem in 2023 too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Jasperserver 5.5 AWS AMI

More specific:

```
/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/esapi/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties
```

Change:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=JASPER_CSRF_TOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=JASPER_CSRF_SESSION_KEY
```

To:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=JASPERCSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=JASPERCSRFSESSIONKEY
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your nginx configuration. I am not sure where the problem is but jasperserver 6 aws AMI seems to make me pull my hair off.

Comment: I don't use jaspersoft anymore. From what I remember, nginx's default behavior is to remove underscores from HTTP headers. Therefore, my solution was to set Jaspersoft to read HTTP headers without the underscore.

Answer (score -2):

My version of Jasperserver looked slightly different, the CSRFguard files are located in `jasperserver/WEB-INF/csrf`

I edited the `jrs.csrfguard.properties` file.